# Can a Variable be dynamically pulled through on a Delphi report not on the data pipeline, SQL database

Tags: delphi

I need to pull through Serial Numbers on a report. There are no serial numbers in the transactional data pipeline. I do have an Audit Number which I can link to the Serial Transactions Table (Audit Number) to dynamically pull through the Serial Number.

Do I set this up using a Variable, or where would I set this up, and what would my code look like?

I am able to pull through static information on a variable based on an ID,but this has been hard coded into the report.

I need something dynamic to pull through.

I expect the code in Delphi to display as. This is SQL code, I can code in SQL, but not so well in Delphi.

```
Select SerialNumber 
from SerialMF
join SerialTX on SerialTX.SNLink = SerialMF.SerialCounter
join postST on postST.cAuditNumber = SerialTX.SNAuditNumber
```

The postST cAuditNumber exists in the report (nothing from Serial Tables).
Output in SQL is correct.

Comment: Which report library are you using, ReportBuilder?

Comment: I am using an report which already exists in Sage Evolution. A new report would use report builder, so I'm assuming this is also report builder.